# Where can i download Raw Bayer images?

Tags: image, image-processing

I would like to play around with Bayer Interpolation techniques & i want to Benchmark my Algorithm. For that where can i get Raw Bayer Test Images? Move me to right forum if needed. If you have any link to files/ Sites Please share it!

Comment: Use your digital camera and take photos?

Comment: good option! but it would be better to take some Standard Test images rt?

Comment: Use some known charts and image quality checks - checkout www.imatest.com

Comment: Already downloaded! But there is no Raw Bayer files given in that sample! only jpeg2 sample is given as sample image. Also tried Rawdigger!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a set of ready-made images [here](http://lcav.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lcav/files/reproductible_research/vandewalleKAS07/VandewalleKAS07_data.zip). It includes only 1 "de facto standard" image however (the lighthouse), since there is no official benchmark.

A common way to test demosaicking is to have an RGB image and to generate the Bayer-sampled image by yourself.
It simply sums up to separating the color channels and applying per-channel masks.
The main advantage of this approach is that you get a ground truth RGB image that you can use to assess the quality of your results.

Comment: If I understand your second paragraph correctly, what you are suggesting is that I take a photograph, throw out 2/3 of the pixel values. Then put the resulting image through my debayer-er, and compare to the original. What I do not understand is how the original can serve as a "ground truth", because presumably, the original is ALSO the product of debayering. In that case, all you are doing is comparing your debayering with someone else's. If theirs is inferior, then your bench mark is going to say that you did "poorly" when in reality, low score is cause by poor "ground truth".

Comment: Am I missing something? I just can help thinking that this is a situation of the blind leading the blind.

Comment: Obviously, you need to start from an image that has few (if no) demosaicking artefacts. Also, some cameras are not equipped with Bayer sensors (e.g., Sigma DSLRs using a Foveon sensor). This is also true for some old scanned images. Finally, your demosaicking algorithm will rely on some assumptions (graient smoothness or sparsity, etc). It is usually a good practice to generate synthetic data according to your assumptions before moving on to real data.